# How to dump memory in windows 2008 64bit server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory-dump

I want to analyze memory leak in my ASP.NET application,
How can I dump memory in windows 2008 64bit server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way can be , Open Task Manager -> Processes -> SELECT_YOUR_APPLICATION_PROCESS.
Then right click & select "create dump file".

Answer (score 2):

Get the [64 bit version of Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx#) and use ADPlus to create a memory dump.